# how to set a native library (.so) on netbeans on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, netbeans

As the title says..
how do I set a native library (.so) on Netbeans on Ubuntu 14.04?

I know on Netbeans Windows I go to:
project properties> run> VM option:
and set:

```
-Djava.library.path="C: and the path of the dll file"
```

Now my question is: 
what should I use instead of the following line:

```
-Djava.library.path="C and the path of the dll file".
```

in Netbeans on Linux Ubuntu 14.04?

what I tried:
I tried using the following line:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/pathof.."
```

and it didn't work. I got the following result:

> Error: Could not find or load main class LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.home.maha.Desktop.ard

Thank you

Comment: Did you use apt-get install to install netbeans in ubuntu?

Comment: i don't remember but yes i might did that. why?

Comment: it actually take care of all the configurations and setting

Comment: how is this related? are you saying what I did is completely correct but there is something wrong with the Netbeans? check the error I posted